# Can not find Gemfire Region using Spring Data

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I was able to run spring-gemfire-examples-master/spring-cache project successfully. However, when I try to connect my local locator, it tells me that region1 could not be found in GemfireCache. However, I can see a connection has been setup in Pulse.
My steps:

1. Open a window command, start a locator1, start a server1,create a region1
2. Change spring-cache...cache-context.xml in sample folder as
3. Change cacheManager accordingly.
4. Run sample as gradlew -q run-spring-cache

I am newbie for Gemfire.

```
<util:properties id="gemfire-props">
    <prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
</util:properties>
<gfe:client-cache id="client-cache"   pool-name="my-pool"></gfe:client-cache>
<gfe:pool id="my-pool" subscription-enabled="true">
 <gfe:locator host="localhost" port="10334"></gfe:locator>
</gfe:pool>
<gfe:lookup-region id="Region1" name="Region1" cache-ref="client-cache">
</gfe:lookup-region>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use

```
<gfe:client-region id="Region1" name="Region1" cache-ref="client-cache"/>
```

lookup-region is associated with cache peers; client-region is used with client caches. Also, modify Main.java accordingly to just load cache-context.xml.